# unrecognized import path on openshift

Tags: go, openshift

I have some local packages defined within my application, for example, I have a crud model located at model/crud/crud.go

Within my application I am calling upon them using `import("model/crud")`, for all of my local dependencies.

This resolves perfectly fine within the context of my application on my local machine, however when I try to push to openshift I get the following error:

`imports model/crud: unrecognized import path "model/crud"`

It looks like when openshift runs the build tool, it is attempting to run `go get` on these imports in order to include them in the build path when compiling.

Is there a better way to resolve vendor specific dependencies without having to create a separate repo for them? I don't want to have to manage two separate repositories if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the full import path. For example `"github.com/user/project/model/crud"`

Comment: These are not on github (at least not publicly), these are packages I have created that are local to my src/ folder. So go get github.com/user/project would not resolve. Even so, managing one application's dependencies in two separate repos makes no sense for this small of an application.

Comment: Even if they are not on github you should be importing from the full src path. Github was just an example.

Comment: Ah, I did try the src path but it looks like openshift is copying files around in such a way based on the go path that immediately breaks these conventions.

Comment: having issues with this myself. in openshift i have a package routes. I have a main.go in the project root the main ackage is here too. not sue how to use the .godir either

Answer (score 2):

To find the import path you are supposed to use, take "$GOPATH/src/[...]/model/crud" and just remove the "$GOPATH/src/" part.

Comment: HectorJ do i find the [..] part??